# Does the DNS service need to be on in order for the caching service to work on OS X Server?

Tags: server.app, dns

I didn't think that caching needed the DNS service to be running in order for it to work. Is this true/false? I've been reading a lot of forums where it says you should get the server DNS right in order to make sure all the other services work but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Our Mac Pro servers (behind NAT) don't have DNS service running and the caching service works fine for both OS X and iOS devices. We simply turned the service on and waited for any files downloaded from Apple to hit the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends:

If you plan to provide the Caching Service to clients with public IP addresses (in other words, not behind a NAT) that are not on the server’s same subnet, you need to create a TXT DNS record in your zone file for the server with the IP address ranges the server is responsible for. [Source](http://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/4.0/?lang=en#/apd6015d9573)

If you plan to provide Caching Service in all or any combinations or portions of subnets of the local network that share a common public IP address you don't need a DNS-Server.

Please check the limitations of the Caching Service [here.](http://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/4.0/?lang=en#/apd74DDE89F-08D2-4E0A-A5CD-155E345EFB83)